# how to update POP3 server in C#

Tags: c#, email, pop3

I'm trying to retrieve data from email and then work with it. Everything is fine, I can get the data, but I need to get the most recent ones. When I run this code and send an email in the process, it doesn't come up until I turn it on. I have tried turning the SSL connection or client to the server on and off and back on again (like some kind of update, but with the same result).
Thanks for any reaction or ideas. :)

```
using EAGetMail;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

namespace PopServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static string _generateFileName(int sequence)
        {
            DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            return string.Format("{0}-{1:000}-{2:000}.eml",
                currentDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", new CultureInfo("en-US")),
                currentDateTime.Millisecond,
                sequence);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                
                string localInbox = string.Format("{0}\\inbox", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                
                if (!Directory.Exists(localInbox))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(localInbox);
                }

                MailServer oServer = new MailServer("popserver.com",
                        "username@mail.com",
                        "password",
                        ServerProtocol.Pop3);
                
                oServer.SSLConnection = true;
                oServer.Port = 995;

                MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");
                oClient.Connect(oServer);

                MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
                Console.WriteLine("Total {0} email(s)\r\n", infos.Length);
//Here I tried to take advantage of the fact that if the application is connected via SSLConnection, it could update, but it only prints the emails before starting the application
                while (oServer.SSLConnection)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
                    {
                        MailInfo info = infos[i];
                        Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                            info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL);


                        Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

                        Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);
                        Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}\r\n", oMail.TextBody);

                     

                        string fileName = _generateFileName(i + 1);
                        string fullPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", localInbox, fileName);


                        oMail.SaveAs(fullPath, true);

                        //Delete email-isRead
                        //oClient.Delete(info);
                    }
                }
               

                
                oClient.Quit();
                Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
            }
        
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try
                {
                    bool help = true;
    do{
                        string localInbox = string.Format("{0}\\inbox", 

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    
                    if (!Directory.Exists(localInbox))
                    {
                    

Directory.CreateDirectory(localInbox);
                    }
    
                    MailServer oServer = new MailServer("popserver.com",
                            "username@mail.com",
                            "password",
                            ServerProtocol.Pop3);
                    
                    oServer.SSLConnection = true;
                    oServer.Port = 995;
    
                    MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");
                    oClient.Connect(oServer);
    
                    MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
                    Console.WriteLine("Total {0} email(s)\r\n", infos.Length);
    //Here I tried to take advantage of the fact that if the application is connected via SSLConnection, it could update, but it only prints the emails before starting the application
                    while (oServer.SSLConnection)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
                        {
                            MailInfo info = infos[i];
                            Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                                info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL);
    
    
                            Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);
    
                            Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);
                            Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}\r\n", oMail.TextBody);
    
                         
    
                            string fileName = _generateFileName(i + 1);
                            string fullPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", localInbox, fileName);
    
    
                            oMail.SaveAs(fullPath, true);
    
                            //Delete email-isRead
                            //oClient.Delete(info);
                        }
                    }
 

    Console.WriteLine("Again?");
                

    Console.WriteLine("1-y");
                    Console.WriteLine("2-n");
                    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (a == 2)
                    {
                        help = false;
                    }
                   //Just easily restarted hole code
                   while(help != false)
    
                    
                    oClient.Quit();
                    Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).